# Mysql escape % and _ for PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, code-injection, sanitize

Is there a special method that will escape % sign and underscore? When i do

```
 PDO->prepare()
```

does it escape % sign and underscore automatically?

i tried using \% or _ but i dont think it works. Also i want to check a string if string contains such characters.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PDO->prepare() why not do in the PDO->execute( array $params ) parameter binding. You do not need to worry about escaping with parameter binding.

Comment: so if i do lets say DB::PARAM_STR or DB::PARAM_INT i wont have to worry about the escapes?

Comment: Yes, the value comes 1:1 in the field, with respect to the field type.

Comment: This answer is categorically wrong as it implies that this sort of parameter binding will properly escape `%` or `_`.  It doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`%` and `_` are never escaped automatically because it is rarely necessary to escape them .. only if they are used in strings with `LIKE`.

You have to handle this manually in php.  You can use `strpos` to check that either of them is in the string, and you can use `str_replace` to do an ad-hoc escape.  You may have to escape backslashes themselves within the string depending upon the string type.